# Update library permissions error (powershell)

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, permissions

I can't understand what's wrong, help please?
Docset's permissions updated successfully, but I can't update permissions for files..

[image: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression]

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

cls
$site = GET-SPSite -Identity "http://url";
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://url/web";
$user = $web.EnsureUser("dom\login");
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions[3]; #Read

$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($user)
$assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role);

$list = $web.Lists["List Name"];

$item = $list.GetItemById(7796);

try {
    #$item.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment);
    Write-Host "Docset opened";
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_;
}

foreach($file in $item.Folder.Files) {
    try {
        $fileAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($user);
        $fileAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
        $file.RoleAssignments.Add($fileAssignment);
        Write-Host "File opened";
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_;
    }
}

$web.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an item here `$item = $list.GetItemById(7796);` but you are calling all the files in the folder, I'm assuming that that "item" is a folder.

The error is because you need to break role inheritance on the ITEM not the FILE. Each File has an Item object that corresponds to it.

```
foreach($file in $item.Folder) {
    try {
        $fileAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($user);
        $fileAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
        $file.Item.RoleAssignments.Add($fileAssignment); //changed
        Write-Host "File opened";
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've forgot, sorry.
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"];